# Delete and Update Records without using SCD, Update strategy in Informatica

Tags: sql, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Please help me to solve this:

I am having Flat file which stores data of 3 locations ( Ahmedabad, Bangalore & Chennai ).
I am loading this data to Database.
Insert is simple.
But when I am changing my location in source i.e., ( Bangalore to Chennai,Ahmedabad or vice versa)
it should insert/update the new record and delete from previous table.

Example:

**Location**

Bangalore   ---> Chennai **(Updated location)**
Chennai
Ahmedabad

After transformation:

**Location**
Chennai
Chennai
Ahmedabad

Comment: Hi - what's your reason for not using an Update Strategy when this type of component is specifically designed for this type of scenario?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.